# Replacing segments in multiple lines with another segment in the same file, which is in multiple folders, using find and sed

Tags: replace, sed, find, segment

I have a the following directory structure of multiple folders:

```
Applications
|
|____Salford_123
|   |_________SomeFile.png
|   |_________AnotherFile.nui
|   |_________MenuSettings.txt
|   |_________Data
|             |_____Settings.txt
|
|____Salford_546
|   |_________SomeFile.png
|   |_________AnotherFile.nui
|   |_________MenuSettings.txt
|   |_________Data
|             |_____Settings.txt
|
|____Salford_789
|   |_________SomeFile.png
|   |_________AnotherFile.nui
|   |_________MenuSettings.txt
|   |_________Data
|             |_____Settings.txt
```

The text file MenuSettings.txt in each folder which has the following contents:

```
AppName: "http://www.bbc.co.uk”
DoubleWidthTile: "False"
TileColor: "0.76 0 0.24 1"
AnimationSize: "10 10"
AppName_xx_XX: “Venice Quays”
AppName_yy_YY: “Venice Quays”
```

This file and its parent folder is generated automatically, multiple times. The first line of the file has a different URL in it every time which could be at any length. Im trying  to have the segment with the URL copied to replace the values in AppName_xx_XX:and AppName_yy_YY:so that it looks like this

```
AppName: "http://www.bbc.co.uk”
DoubleWidthTile: "False"
TileColor: "0.76 0 0.24 1"
AnimationSize: "10 10"
AppName_xx_XX: “http://www.bbc.co.uk”
AppName_yy_YY: “http://www.bbc.co.uk”
```

The entries for AppName_xx_XX: and AppName_yy_YY: would have any word generated in it at any length with spaces and punctuation. The xx and yy part of the string  would be any 2 characters. So I used "find" to search recursively through the folders and a "sed" command to copy and replace the segments, which outputs to another file, which I would then mv -v back to the original.

```
find salford* -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec sh -c '(cd {} && 

cat MenuSettings.txt | sed -e 's/AppName\_en\_[[A-Z]]\:[[:blank:]]\"[[:alpha:]]*.\"/AppName\:[[:space:]]\"[[:alpha:]]*.[[:alpha:]]*.[[:alpha:]]*.\"/g' > MenuSettings3.txt

)' ';'
```

The bash file runs with no errors but fails to work, as file it generates shows no changes. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed '/^AppName: */{h;s///;x;}; /^\(AppName_.._..:\).*/{s//\1/;G;s/\n/ /;}' MenuSettings.txt
AppName: "http://www.bbc.co.uk”
DoubleWidthTile: "False"
TileColor: "0.76 0 0.24 1"
AnimationSize: "10 10"
AppName_xx_XX: "http://www.bbc.co.uk”
AppName_yy_YY: "http://www.bbc.co.uk”
```

I worked from your description to make the above sed command.  I'm making use of the hold buffer to keep the URL, and for the xx/yy lines appending from the hold buffer after getting rid of the original value.

The first bracketed expression uses hold to make a copy of the line in the hold buffer.
The `s///` reuses the last pattern and replaces it with nothing, leaving just the quoted URL.  The `x` exchanges the edited line for the copy, so it outputs the original line while keeping the URL in the hold buffer.

The next bracketed expression uses `s//\1/` to reuse the last pattern and replace the match with the captured characters.  `G` appends the hold buffer contents to the end of the pattern space, after the newline.  The `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline with a space.

Comment: Thanks for this @dancancode, using hold in sed is something I didn't realise until now. Can holding a segment apply between files?

Comment: sed treats multiple file arguments as a stream of input.  The hold buffer is in memory, so when sed exits, the hold buffer is gone (unless you write it to a file with the `w` command).  If you give multiple files to a single sed command (and you're **not** using the `-i` in-place switch) a value in the hold buffer can be used with input from from the subsequent files.